# 1000 nuts in 500 cakes, random variable X = the number of nuts in a random cake

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A baker puts $1000$ nuts the mixture for making $500$ cakes. $X$ is a random variable indicating the number of nuts in a randomly chosen cake, which is at most 5. Find the distribution of $X$ and the probability that a randomly chosen cake has exactly $2$ nuts.

Now, if the constrain with $5$ nuts didn't exist, i guess $X \sim Po(2)$. Then the probability of $2$ nuts in a cake is $P(X = 2) = \frac{2^2}{2!}e^{-2} = \frac{2}{e^2}$.

Any help in solving the original problem?

Comment: It depends on how the nuts are put in: (a) putting each nut in at random until a cake is full after which it is avoided; or (b) putting each nut in at random but starting right from the beginning if any cake gets more then $5$.  (a) and (b) will produce different answers.

Comment: Not particularly useful, but I think there may be just over $5 \times 10^{377}$ different ways to distribute the nuts, or more precisely 517859237035877684440736997142861972747031702748657010093676498336920589347658860569140180299548899401525886550358729972486427165639481585804501496625870275589414537921847477296943268128600069620028341093545220642242031284811642889658389485858009758310660935626616135082258430353682922456996104272826478048750020984426306273277713739228917761593007620760305547643349437063983775

Comment: I think (b) is closer to the problem description, so let's solve (b).